# Posting File to WebServer with Java

Tags: java, html, post, file-upload

I'm trying to post a file to a ASP.NET WEB API (C#) Server with a local Java application.
Basically I'm trying to reproduce the following HTML code in Java SE:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://localhost:50447/api/files/">
<div>
    <label for="image1">Image File</label>
    <input name="image1" type="file" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

What's the simplest way to do this? I'd like to avoid using Apache..
Something like:

```
String urlToConnect = "http://localhost:50447/api/files/";
    String paramToSend = "";
    File fileToUpload = new File("C:/Users/aa/Desktop/sample_signed.pdf");
    String boundary = Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis()); // Just generate some unique random value.

    URLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = new URL(urlToConnect).openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    connection.setDoOutput(true); // This sets request method to POST.
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    PrintWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));

        writer.println("--" + boundary);
        writer.println("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"paramToSend\"");
        writer.println("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
        writer.println();
        writer.println(paramToSend);

        writer.println("--" + boundary);
        writer.println("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileToUpload\"; filename=\"sample_signed.pdf\"");
        writer.println("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
        writer.println();
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileToUpload), "UTF-8"));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
                    writer.println(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) try { reader.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
        }

        writer.println("--" + boundary + "--");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e2) {

        e2.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e2) {

        e2.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (writer != null) writer.close();
    }

    // Connection is lazily executed whenever you request any status.
    int responseCode = 0;
    try {
        responseCode = ((HttpURLConnection) connection).getResponseCode();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(responseCode);
```

Using only URLConnections.. This code isn't working properly.. It sends the file, but some content is lost and I don't know why.. My HTML sample works perfectly..

Can you help me?

Thank you for your attention,
Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Another approach, using DataOutputStream.

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(absolutePath);
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:50447/api/files/");

        // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
        conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
        conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", filename);

        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        // create a buffer of  maximum size
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // read file and write it into form...
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize); 

        while (bytesRead > 0) {

            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

        }

        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);


        // Responses from the server (code and message)
        serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
        System.out.println(serverResponseMessage);

        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a reader and writer combination, while you are transferring binary data. You should use streams when working with binary data.

So instead of a BufferedReader, use a normal InputStream buffered to read the file and do not wrap the output stream you get from the URLConnection.

Read bytes instead of strings in the read loop. So replace the part starting with BufferedReader until the finally just before the boundary write with:

```
            OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
            InputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(fileToUpload);
            try {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int length;
                while ((length = fileIn.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                output.flush();
            } finally {

                if (fileIn != null) try { fileIn.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
            }
```

Comment: To not to wrap the output stream I'd have to cut this: writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8")); If I do this, how do I write the file bytes to the outputstream?

Comment: I replaced my code, but still no luck.. I did maintain the PrintWriter to write the header file and the boundary.. Do I remove that part too?

Comment: Can you actually see what parts aren't received on the server side? That would help pin-pointing the problem.

Comment: In this moment, the server-side doesn't receive any part.. I replaced "BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileToUpload), "UTF-8"));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
                    writer.println(line);
                } " for your code, and right now he doesn't receive any part..

Comment: The request arrives in the server, but when it searchs for files, it can't find any one..

Comment: That is a bit vague. You send a stream of text and binary. It would help if you can get a log of what the server actually receives. If you can't get a log from the server, you might use a tool like wireshark to see what the network traffic actually is.

Comment: In my server (C#): var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root); when I check for MultiPartFileData in provider.FileData it can't find any file.. It's probably of being text and binary.. But it has to be, right? With only text the file arrives, but with no text inside.. I don't understand why.. With HTML it receives the file perfectly..

Comment: I tried another approach. I used DataOutputStream to write bytes. The header info is sent also with dataouputstream.writeBytes("header...") and it worked! Thank you

Comment: Ok great. Maybe you should add the solution to your question and accept your or my answer so this question is tagged as answered.